# CopyPicture sometimes throws error after selecting a group of shapes

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to copy an image of three charts, grouped on the worksheet as `Group 8`.

The routine loops through a selected dataset plotting each sample as a batch job.

Historically, I was able to:

```
ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range("Group 8").Select
Selection.CopyPicture xlScreen, xlPicture
```

Running this macro from the worksheet gets a 400 error.

Running straight from the code sheet, gives a

> 1004 - App-defined or obj-defined error.

Running with a breakpoint on the `Select` statement and stepping through the `CopyPicture`, it works.
Running on my laptop, it *all* works as the worksheet macro.
Running on my colleague's desktop, it *all* works.
Running just the `CopyPicture` command as a single line macro, works.

Other threads suggest that MS has fiddled with the clipboard.
Through various code-execution delaying tactics, others had their problem resolved.
e.g., 'Sleep for 500ms'.

---

I found a working solution in MS community posting by V. Arya.
Inserting this line prior to the `CopyPicture` does seem to be a clipboard delay.

```
Do: DoEvents: Loop Until Application.Ready
```

I am still interested in any insights.

Comment: Using `Select` is always a risk as it is not very reliable. Since it is very obvious that the issue occurs because there is a time-gap between selecting your group and the application beeing ready to take a picture of that, I don't get what exactly you are asking for. You gave yourself the correct answer already. `Select` is (in some cases, or some computers) too slow and you have to make sure the application is ready before taking the picture. You do that with exactly the code you have found. No more magic here. If you still have a question please clarify.

Comment: Thanks for the response, PEH. I did find a workaround but was curious if others had more insight into a "new" slow clipboard issue. Also, you and other threads suggest not using the "select" approach, that it's unreliable. When I use the alternative coding

Comment: without Selecting: 
ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range("Group 8").CopyPicture xlScreen, xlPicture
the "Object doesn't support this property or method" error appears.  Your advice would be helpful here.  Also, I don't know how this code would handle the clipboard delay.

Comment: Yes, there are some cases where `.Select` is not avoidable. Still it can be unreliable in these cases. Therefore this loop just runs until the application is ready to do the copy. `DoEvents` just means give Excel time to perform any events if needed.